# R.java file cannot be resolved after importing Google Play Services

Tags: android, google-play-services, r.java-file

I have created an Android app in that when I imports Google Play Services library it removes R.java file.

I had clean and build the project and also restarts the eclipse but can't get the R.java file.

How to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: R.java file is auto generated as you know, so it will generate automatically when you build your project. Then also if you not build your project then check Resource folder, there might be a issue.

Comment: Problem might be there in your resource folder.

Comment: What will be the problem?

Comment: @SwetaSharma clearly told you that check resource folder, and check below in "problem" tab or "Error Log" tab or in "console" tab, you will see there.

Comment: You must be having problem with xml in res folder like misspelling. Check xmls first then we will see

Comment: @Roon13, Without importing Google Play Services lib its works fine but when I imports google play services library R.java file removes. So if there is problem in xmls first its not runs.

Comment: @pratt, do you have any idea about - http://stackoverflow.com/q/31738487/4352803

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution myself.

I just changed the android:minSdkVersion="8" to android:minSdkVersion="14" in AndroidManifest.xml file and problem solved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here : https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup

Here's different steps to proceed for setting up Google Play Services :

1. Copy the library project at /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/ to the location where you maintain your Android app projects.
2. Import the library project into your Eclipse workspace. Click File > Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace, and browse to the copy of the library project to import it.
3. In your app project, reference Google Play services library project. [See Referencing a Library Project for Eclipse](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) for more information on how to do this.

**Note:** Don't forget to copy the library to your development workspace :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check your resource file error.
after solving your resource xml file error remove import android.R; from your java file and import com.your.package.name.R; in your java